Nuxt dev serv and nginx
How to config nginx for nuxt dev?
nginx conf now:
    
rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_buffering         on;
        proxy_cache_valid   200 1d;
        proxy_cache_use_stale   error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;

        proxy_pass              http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_read_timeout  1m;
        proxy_connect_timeout   1m;
    }

but I get these errors

In web I don't find some info about this errors. For test I start server Apache and all works fine. How to config nginx for normal work?

What are the corresponding entries from the nginx error log (the first thing you should check in case of internal server error)? And, although unrelated, what's the purpose of the rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break; directive?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
